# Simple autohosted SharePoint app is never firing the remote event receiver

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

Edit: I changed this to a SharePoint-hosted app that is just using a web part to display the announcements. It's still failing to ever hit the event

```
<AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="full" WebPartOrder="0">
    <![CDATA[ 
  <webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
  <metaData>
  <type
name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart,
Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <importErrorMessage>
  Cannot import this Web Part.
  </importErrorMessage>
  </metaData>
  <data>
    <properties>
      <property name="Title"
       type="string">Announcements</property>
      <property name="ListDisplayName"
       type="string">Announcements</property> 
       <property name="ChromeType"
       type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
    </properties>
  </data>
</webPart>
```

]]>

and then I have a /Services/AnnouncementsReceiver.svc, generated by VS2013, with the following:

```
    public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

        switch (properties.EventType)
        {
            // demonstrate ability to modify prior to adding
            case SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdding:
                result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("Body", properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Body"] += "\n ** For internal use only ** \n");
                break;

            // demonstrate ability to cancel a delete event
            case SPRemoteEventType.ItemDeleting:
                result.ErrorMessage = "Items cannot be deleted from this list";
                result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelWithError;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The problem is that this code is never firing. I can create any number of list items and the event never fires. I've even made it throw an immediate exception as well as always return an error, but it's never triggering. It's definitely tied to the app's Announcements list and it should be catching the correct events. Here's a snippet from Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="10000">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>AnnouncementsReceiverItemAdding</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/AnnouncementsReceiver.svc</Url>
    </Receiver>
    <Receiver>
      <Name>AnnouncementsReceiverItemDeleting</Name>
      <Type>ItemDeleting</Type>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/AnnouncementsReceiver.svc</Url>
    </Receiver>
    <Receiver>
      <Name>AnnouncementsReceiverItemAdded</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/AnnouncementsReceiver.svc</Url>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

I've also confirmed that it's being deployed by the Package.package. I'm at my wit's end.

Comment: Where are you wiring up your Button1_Click event handler?

Comment: Default.aspx. Pretty basic:    
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Add Announcement" />
...

Comment: What is the rest of the elements.xml? Did you define the listtemplateid of the "Receivers" tag?

Comment: Added the whole thing to the OP. It does have a ListTemplateID

Answer (score 0):

Yep, deployment of apps in VS 2013 is fussy as cache, like always, gets out of step with reality (cache the bane of my existence!). Try this whenever things stop working as they should:

1. Exit VS 2013
2. Run these commands from a cmd prompt:
   net stop sptimerv4, 
   iisreset /noforce /timeout:300, 
   net start sptimerv4
3. Close all browser windows, start VS 2013, set your break point, press play.

Rinse and repeat as required.